# Make static member persistent

Tags: vb.net, serialization, persistence, static-members

I have one class with a private static (shared, since I'm in VB.BET) field and its associated public static property, since it stores one variable that should be the same to all the instances of this class.

My Class looks like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class NitrogenController
    Private _active As Boolean
    Private Shared _controlInterval As TimeSpan
    Private _lastControlTime As Date

    Public Property Active() As Boolean
    Public Shared Property ControlInterval() As System.TimeSpan

    'other properies that must be persisted

    Public Function Control() As Boolean
        If Not Now > _lastControlTime.Add(_controlInterval) Or Not _active Then
            Return False
        Else
            DoControl()
            _lastControlTime = Now
            Return True
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

The problem arrives when trying to binary serialize these kind of objects, since this shared field is nos being properly stored and returns to its default value when deserializing.

I suppose this is the expected behaviour, so my question is... how can I make a shared field persistent? I have read some comments to similar questions that say that this is a bad design, but it really makes sense (AFAIK) in my case, since this variable should be the same to all the object, but can be changed by the user and therefore should be stored.

Can you suggest another way of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have read, in my opinion, is correct.  This is, likely, a bad design.  However, if you must, there are two ways to do this with the `XmlSerializer`.  The easy way would be to simply add a public instance (non-shared) property which has a getter and setter which simply wrap the shared property, for instance:

```
Public MustInherit Class NitrogenController
    Public Shared Property ControlInterval As TimeSpan

    Public Property CurrentControlInterval() As TimeSpan
        Get
            Return ControlInterval 
        End Get
        Set(value As TimeSpan)
            ControlInterval = value
        End Set        
    End Property
End Class
```

If you aren't satisfied with that method, the second, more involved, option would be to override the default serialization logic by implementing the `ISerializable` interface.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. But I still have the base question unsolved... why is this a bad design? How can I handle the need of having a variable that should be the same for all the Controllers? Should I pass it as an argument to Control() function?

Comment: Well, shared members are essentially just global-state, which has always been and always will be discouraged, since it makes code unpredictable (i.e., each time you call a method, it doe not necessarily have the same effect).  Private shared data is slightly better in the sense that it's at least encapsulated, but it still causes the unpredictability.  There's always exceptions to every rule, but generally speaking, its best to pass values as arguments or have them be looked up through some other object (perhaps given at time of construction) when needed.

Comment: However, more than all that, this just seems like a strange idea.  If the value is shared among all of the objects, why would you want to persist a separate copy of that value with each object?  First, it's wasteful, but more importantly, what do you do if the different copies of the value don't agree with each other?  It allows the values to get out of sync.  It would seem like you'd want to store the value separately, somewhere, outside of any of the controller objects' persisted state.

Comment: Another reason why globals are bad is because it makes your code less flexible and less reusable.  What if, some day, you wanted to create two separate *sets* of `NitrogenController` objects in memory, at the same time, but have each set operating on a different interval.  If they are all hard-wired to use that global value, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for all that information, I've solved many questions I had in mind for some time. Before they were "don't-do-that" rules, now I understand why I should apply them.